# Disturbance rejection of PID controller with low sampling rate

Tags: arduino, control, matlab

I have a closed-loop system with the following discrete-time plant:

$P(z) = \frac{0.1262}{z^2-0.3303z+0.07517}$

With a fixed (and horrendously low) sampling time of 0.05 seconds. The plant has a time constant of approximately 0.03 seconds - this was calculated using MATLABs System Identification Toolbox.

I am trying to design a PI/PID controller that will attenuate load disturbances (injected after the plant) with frequencies < 1 Hz without amplifying higher frequencies. No matter how much I play with the gain and phase margins, I cannot seem to achieve this.

Seen below, is a picture showing a nasty bump between 1 and 6 Hz (circled in red) that I cannot seem to remove and retaining disturbance rejection at low frequencies.

[image]

I believe that this is an impossible task to accomplish with such a low sampling rate. If so, are there any other control typologies I can take a look at? In the past, I designed a [Smith predictor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/control-of-processes-with-long-dead-time-the-smith-predictor.html), and yes it improved disturbance rejection but not by very much - I am still getting amplification at higher frequencies.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Because the plant has a delay of two samples it will never be possible to cancel the disturbances completely, because then you would have to predict the disturbance those two samples ahead of time. Also a Smith predictor is therefore only useful for obtaining a desirable complementary sensitivity transfer function.

I also believe your are limited by the [waterbed effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode%27s_sensitivity_integral). According to this attenuating below 1 Hz and not amplify above that would be impossible. I gave it a try myself and was able to limit the peek of the sensitivity function to 4.06 dB while still satisfying the attenuating below 1 Hz. However lowering it to attenuating below 0.6 Hz gave me a peek of only 1.54 dB. Namely the waterbed effect roughly says that if you want to lower the magnitude of the sensitivity in a certain frequency range, then it has to go up somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you again very much. I am realizing how difficult these dynamics are. I am considering putting a low-pass filter in the feedback line, so the PID controller does not attempt to compensate for disturbances > 1 Hz. I only care about attenuating low frequencies (< 1 Hz). A high order filter will inject so much phase delay - I believe. I feel like this is not good practice because in general this would equate to lower gains on the controller.

Comment: Would increase sampling rate help with the waterbed effect? Also, can you suggest any reading material on disturbance rejection and sampling rate?